# Matrix directional derivative for LQR solution via Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am following a textbook derivation for the solution to the LQR problem in optimal control and am having trouble getting the same expression as the author. I think my issue is just in taking the directional derivatives of the quadratic terms. The problem is as follows.

We consider a nonlinear system
$$\mathbf{\dot{x}} = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x,u}) \qquad \mathbf{x}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbf{u}(t)\in \mathbb{R}^m$$
We seek to minimize the cost function

$$ J = \int_0^{\tau} \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Qx} + \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{Ru})dt +  \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Q_fx}) $$

Where $\mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{Q}_f, \mathbf{R}$  are symmetric and positive-definite. We use a Lagrange multiplier $\mathbf{\lambda}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the augmented cost function
$$H = J +\int_0^\tau \mathbf{\lambda}^T (\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x,u})-\mathbf{\dot{x}})dt $$
By the Lagrange multiplier theroem, we require the conditions
$$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{\lambda}} = 0, 
\quad\frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = 0,\quad
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{u}}=0$$

Where I get lost is in the next step, where the author takes directional derivatives of H with respect to $\mathbf{\lambda}, \mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{u}$. The book has

$$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{\lambda}} \cdot \delta \mathbf{\lambda} = 
\int_0^\tau \delta \mathbf{\lambda}^T(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x,u})-\mathbf{\dot{x}}) dt
 = 0 \quad \forall \delta \mathbf{\lambda}$$
Which of course requires the integrand to be $0$. I (think I) see how this one works out, but where I don't follow is in the calculation of

$$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{u}} \cdot \delta \mathbf{u} = 
\int_0^{\tau} \left (\frac{1}{2}(\delta \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{Ru} + \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{R}\delta \mathbf{u}) + \lambda^T \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{u}} \delta \lambda\right)dt$$
And a similar form for $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \cdot \delta \mathbf{x}$

If anyone could help show how the derivative of the quadratic term $\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{Ru}$ works out, it would be greatly appreciated. My matrix calculus is very rusty and I never did too much of it in the first place. I imagine my mistake lies in appllying the product rule for these terms.

A more succinct question might be for me to ask how to calculate
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{u}} \left(\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{Ru} \right) \cdot \delta \mathbf{u} $$

Note: this is my first post on here, so if I am missing any details/context or if there are any formatting errors, etc. please let me know.

Thank you in advance!!